# Sed find/inline replace, escaping some characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, find

I have a bunch of DB connection settings that I need to replace and was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction with sed. Typically I use a find and sed combo to perform this action, like this:

```
sudo find . -name "*.php" -print0 |
sudo xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's#:/usr/share/php/pear:#:/usr/lib/php5/pear/:/usr/share/php/pear:#g'
```

But for the DB connection strings I need to replace lines that look like this:

```
define('DBUSER', 'dbuser');
```

For various reasons I can't just do a sed on the username itself, so I need to define the replace-able text more strictly. Unfortunately my limited skills with regex are failing me on how I would properly escape that whole sequence so that it can be found by sed and replaced properly. What would I need to do to essentially use the same find/sed command I typically use to replace the usernames in those DBUSER strings? I tried the to backslash-escape the single quotes, as well as double-quote each single-quote, and none of that worked. This is on an up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04 system without any fancy customization.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might just need to double \ escape them. One \ for `bash`, and another one for `sed`.

Comment: @CarlTashian no, you cannot use a single quote within a single-quote-delimited shell script no matter what the tool is you are using (sed, awk, etc.) and no matter how many times you try to escape it.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, that makes sense.

Comment: @CarlTashian You're welcome. No, never double quote a script unless it's absolutely necessary and you have a very specific purpose in mind related to the behavior produced by double quoting a script (i.e. you are trying to make something happen, not trying to stop something from happening, and double quoting is THE way to do it) and fully understand the caveats/gothcas. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37145091/1745001) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell will not allow you to use a single quote within a single-quote-delimited shell script no matter what the tool is you are using (sed, awk, etc.) and no matter how many times you try to escape it.

The usual way to do this with sed is to add single quotes within the sed command line to momentarily jump back out of sed and into shell:

```
sed 'in sed'back in shell'in sed'
```

and escape the single quote once there

```
sed 'in sed'\''in sed'
```

Specifically:

```
$ echo "foo define('DBUSER', 'dbuser'); bar" |
    sed 's/define('\''DBUSER'\'', '\''dbuser'\'');/you win $100/'
foo you win $100 bar

$ echo "foo define('DBUSER', 'dbuser'); bar" |
    sed 's/define('\''DBUSER'\'', '\''dbuser'\'');/voila!/'
foo voila! bar
```

Never enclose a sed script or any other script with double quotes instead of single (another oft-suggested approach to solving this problem) because although that **seems** simple, as with most things that seem simple in shell programming, it's very fragile and you'll then have to be on the lookout for and deal with variable expansion and other issues, e.g.:

```
$ echo "foo define('DBUSER', 'dbuser'); bar" |
    sed "s/define('DBUSER', 'dbuser');/you win $100/"
foo you win 00 bar

$ echo "foo define('DBUSER', 'dbuser'); bar" |
    sed "s/define('DBUSER', 'dbuser');/voila!/"
-bash: !/: event not found
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the thorough explanation and examples!

Answer (score 1):

You may need three backslashes to represent the single quote character inside the regexp. Here's why:

```
~$ echo 'sdfsdf'
sdfsdf
~$ echo \'sdfsdf\'
'sdfsdf'
~$ echo \\'sdfsdf\\'
\sdfsdf\\
~$ echo \\\'sdfsdf\\\'
\'sdfsdf\'
```

Edit: Actually this doesn't work for `sed`. But if you use double quotes around the regular expression, you should only need one backslash:

```
~$ sed -e "s#\'hi\'#abc#g"
'hi'
abc
```